# What's wrong with this MySQL Stored Function?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Having trouble getting this to apply in MySQL Workbench 5.2.15

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE 
    DEFINER=`potts`@`%` 
    FUNCTION 
        `potts`.`fn_create_category_test`  (test_arg VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS int

BEGIN

    DECLARE new_id int;
    SET new_id = 8;
    RETURN new_id;

END//
```

The actual function will have a lot more between `BEGIN` and `END` but as it stands, even this 3 liner won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: it works for me. obvious possible problems: does the database `potts` exist? Doesn't the function `fn_create_category_test` exist already in `potts`? Does the user `potts' exist? Does the user `potts` have the necessary privileges to create a function in the database `potts` ?

Comment: yes, no, yes and yes. i'm putting it down to a bug in that version, it now runs fine in mysql query browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fn_create_category_test` (test_arg varchar(50))
   RETURNS INT
BEGIN

DECLARE new_id int;
set new_id=8;
return new_id;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Works fine for me, try getting rid of DEFINER?